# Replacing Space with Minus, but onlyWithin Parentheses

Tags: regex, delphi

I have a string like this:

> $VarCond='EBx(_ _ _ _:_)' if EB='(_ _ _ _:_)',

and i need to replace any space in the substrings in brackets by a minus, but not the other spaces, so in the end it should look like:

> $VarCond='EBx(_-_-_-_:_)' if EB='(_-_-_-_:_)',

Is this possible via regex replace?

Edit: Other examples:

> $VarCond='EBx(Z Z Z)' if EB='(Z Z Z)',
>   $VarCond='EBx(_+_ L LIL L)' if EB='(_+_ L LIL L)',

Comment: What regex flavor / engine do you plan to use?

Comment: Delphi (XE3) TRegex class

Comment: Thanks, added Delphi tag to the question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search: `[ ](?=[^(]*\))` (the brackets at the beginning are optional but make it easier to see the space).

Replace: `-`

This assumes that your parentheses are balanced, as in your example, and `(not (nested))`

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/52), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- `[ ]` matches a space character (brackets are optional)
- The lookahead `(?=[^(]*\))` asserts that what follows is any number of chars that are not an opening par, followed by a closing par. This ensure we are inside the pars.

**In Delphi**

```
var
    ResultString: string;

ResultString := '';
try
    ResultString := TRegEx.Replace(SubjectString, ' (?=[^(]*\))', '-', [roMultiLine]);
except
    on E: ERegularExpressionError do begin
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
    end;
end;
```

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

```
Pattern: (?<=\()(.) (.) (.) (.:.)(?=\))
Replace: \1-\2-\3-\4
```

Alternatively, simpler is to just use the parens literally instead of lookahead and lookbehind:

```
Pattern: \((.) (.) (.) (.:.)\)
Replace: (\1-\2-\3-\4)
```

Note that if your language requires it, you may need to use `$1-$2...` in the replacement instead of `\1-\2...`.

Here's an example with PHP:

```
$s="\$VarCond='EBx(_ _ _ _:_)' if EB='(_ _ _ _:_)',";

echo preg_replace('/(?<=\()(.) (.) (.) (.:.)(?=\))/', '\1-\2-\3-\4', $s);

// $VarCond='EBx(_-_-_-_:_)' if EB='(_-_-_-_:_)',
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works for the special string I have provided - but there are other ones, where the strings inside brackets look a bit different, so i am searching for a more universal solution

Comment: You provided test case, I provided solution. If you have more possible formats, you should have shown them all. Otherwise you may need find&replace with callback, because not everything can be done in pure regex.